# Implement a Master Detail Page inside a Tabbed Page in Xamarin Forms (with Prism)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I have been trying to create a **Xamarin Forms** App using **Prism** that works on **both phones and tablets**.

For the tablet layout I'm trying to create something similar to the draft image below while still **reusing the Pages/ViewModels from the phone**.

[image: structure of pages]

### What I have tried:

- **Using a TabbedPage where each Tab contains a MasterDetailPage. There are two issues with this solution**:

  1. Xamarin only recommends using a MasterDetailPage as the root page
  2. I managed to implement this "solution" but probably due to the reason above the xaml of the pages inside the MasterDetailPage don't bind correctly to their ViewModels.
- **Using a TabbedPage in which each Tab contains a Page divided in two parts which have a ContentView**:

  1. This solution works, but I can't reuse the Page from the Phone version directly on the layout.
  2. I did try using Prism [Partial Views](http://brianlagunas.com/whats-new-prism-7-1/) to implement this solution, but I think the parent Page needs to contain the ViewModel that is going to be used by the ContentView which wouldn't work in this scenario (because it's going to contain two View Models).
- **Not sharing the Pages/ContentViews/ViewModels between phone and tablet**:

  1. This solution works, because I can implement the MasterDetailPage with ContentViews but there's is no code being shared for pages/views that basically do exactly same thing so it's really not ideal.

**Any idea on how I can implement this layout while still sharing the Views and View Models between the Phone and Tablet implementations?**

Note: This app is for Android, iOS and UWP using Xamarin Forms 3.4 and Prism 7.1

Comment: AFAIK you can't nest a Master Detail inside of a tabbed page

Comment: As @Jason said, you can't nest master detail inside tabbed page. You could create a component that contains a Grid with two columns, on the left use a ListView for the items and on the right side insert differents ContentViews.

Comment: Not possible sorry!

Comment: Thanks everyone. indeed using the MasterDetail inside a TabbedPage is out of the question.
I think I might be able to do this using Prism PartialViews though. Still investigating and will update if I manage to do it.

Comment: I also want to do the same layout to optimise the use of space on UWP desktop (and tablet). I don't really get why a TabbedPage can be a child page but MasterDetailPage can't. What did you go with in the end?

Comment: @user2240342 Xamarin itself recommends not using MasterDetail inside TabbedPage. The reason I suspect is due to limitations with the MasterDetail in iOS/Android.

Anyway, my solution was creating a custom control myself that mimics the MasterDetail, but that means I had to implement the entire Navigation handling for that custom control (and navigation stacks, etc)